# Tagging: latex3 vs expl3

Tags: discussion, tagging, questions

Several questions I’ve asked on TeX.SE have been related to LaTeX3 and Expl3, and I’ve found myself using both [latex3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex3) and [expl3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expl3). This is probably redundant.

When should a question be tagged [latex3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex3) and when [expl3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expl3)?

Should the tags be merged?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

LaTeX3 is much more than expl3.

- LaTeX3 is about the LaTeX3 project, it is about the successor of LaTeX 2e, i.e. the *format* LaTeX3, it is about all the different concepts like coffins or the idea of `xtemplate`...
- expl3 however is the *programming layer* of LaTeX3, i.e., one part of many.

I'd tag a question {expl3} (in addition to the {latex3} tag) when the question is about the programming language and its usage, i.e., about all the stuff in [interface3](http://texdoc.net/pkg/interface3) like for example [What is the difference between \cs_if_exist:NTF and \cs_if_free:NTF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44003/what-is-the-difference-between-cs-if-existntf-and-cs-if-freentf), and {latex3} in all cases where the question goes beyond, like [your `xtemplate` question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117984/using-latex3s-xtemplate) or [What can *I* do to help the LaTeX3 Project](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45838/what-can-i-do-to-help-the-latex3-project).

I've noticed, however, that many people don't seem to make a distinction between LaTeX3 and expl3 and also the current tagging doesn't seem to be consistent.

Comment: I don't think the tags should be 'either/or'. The LaTeX3 tag should be added to any question that deals with LaTeX3 (including questions that are tagged [tag:expl3]).

Comment: @Alan: you misunderstood me: when I said that expl3 is part of LaTeX3 I thought it implicitly stated that a question about expl3 is also about LaTeX3 but not the other way around :) Maybe I wasn't clear on that...

Comment: So pretty much everything tagged [tag:expl3], [tag:xtemplate], _etc._, _etc._, should **also** be tagged [tag:latex3]? (Though probably not everything tagged [tag:xparse], since that’s being used without thinking about LaTeX3.)

Comment: @J.C.Salomon in my opinion: yes

Answer (score 8):

`expl3` is a package that is part of the LaTeX3 project. There are other packages that are also part of LaTeX3 (e.g. the `xparse` and `xcoffins` packages, etc.). So the tags (should) serve different purposes: the [latex3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex3) tag deals with any aspect of LaTeX3, while the [expl3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expl3) tag deals specifically with the functionality that `expl3` provides.  So  I don't think the tags should be merged, and your use of both tags is entirely appropriate.

Comment: So when is [tag:latex3] ever needed; shouldn’t [tag:expl3] or [tag:xwhatever] usually be sufficient?

Comment: No, there's an advantage to having more general tags as well as more specific tags.  For example, I can 'follow' the [tag:latex3] tag without having to worry about following each of the individual package tags.

Comment: @J.C.Salomon Also, I suppose one might ask a question on general latex3 plans or philosophy.